# How to pass arguments to a controller ruby method from javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a select list something like this in my views

```
<select class="sel_list_size" id="product", onchange="build_url('dynamic_div')">
    <%= options_for_select(get_product) %>
</select>
```

I have a controller method which will run a command as per the selected value.

```
def get_inner_dir_of_products(product)
    cmd = `curl #{@base_url[0]}/#{product}/`
    result = JSON.parse(cmd)
    @inner_dirs = []
    result.each_with_index do |element, _index|
        @inner_dirs.append([element['name'], _index + 1])
    end
    @inner_dirs
end
```

i have a javascript to call that method.

```
function build_url(div_var) {
    var selected_index = product.selectedIndex;
    var selected_value = product.options[product.selectedIndex].text;
    var selSpan = document.createElement('span');
    $.ajax({
      url: '/get_inner_dir_of_products',
      type: 'GET',
      data: { selected_value }
    })
    // code to build a select list goes here
}
```

i know this ajax call won't work. How to call the controller method from the views?

Comment: You almost got it. You now only need to 1) define a proper route that'll resolve requests to that controller action and 2) fetch action parameters from `params` object.

Comment: Oh, and while that shelling out to `curl` _could_ probably work, you need to rewrite it to using Net::HTTP or RestClient or Faraday (or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `routes.db` file, you need to connect the path you want to access from javascript to the controller method:

```
get '/get_inner_dir_of_products' => 'youramazingcontroller#get_inner_dir_of_products'
```

Now, when you make calls to the server at `/get_inner_dir_of_products`, Rails knows to send that to the controller's get_inner_dir_of_products method.

The `get_inner_dir_of_products` method can access parameters passed to that method using the `params` object.

```
@some_value = params[:somevalue]
```

You can set the name of the param in javascript:

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/get_inner_dir_of_products',
  type: 'GET',
  data: { somevalue: selected_value }, 
  // etc.
})
```

Comment: It Worked. Thanks